# App structure iOS and Realm: create database when app is installed

Tags: ios, realm

I am very new to iOS. I am developing an app with data persistence. I have decided to use Realm for that purpose.

I must to create the database and load data the first time that app runs. I get data from a Web Service in JSON format. I will implement some strategy to update this database later, maybe with iOS Silent Push notifications.

I have read and I have worked about Realm, loading data from JSON... to learn about that.

Now, I need to apply this in my project but I don't know how to start. I need some clues about general idea for the app:

How can I organize my app to load data when it is installed? At what point should I create the database and load data?

I have thought to create a global Realm object y AppDelegate and use it as a global variable. Is it a good idea?

Do I need to set a path for my database? Can I user default path?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a place to start, you can check out the example apps of this UI component add-on for Realm: [ABFRealmGridController](https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmGridController).

The controller is a subclass of `UICollectionView` and the example app should demonstrate most of the functionality you are curious about. The example uses the controller to display the top news stories from the New York Times. This involves making a request to their API and loading the JSON response data into Realm.

When to load the data is dependent on how you want the app to function. If the data will be the same for each user, you could bundle the Realm file with the app pre-populated with data.

The `ABFRealmGridController` example loads data when the user clicks the refresh button and performs the JSON handling on a background thread; a general best-practice.

Finally, unless you have multiple Realms or need to store the file in a specific path, it is probably simplest to use the default path.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will check out the example.